# How to get Salesforce frozen Users in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to send communications to my Salesforce Internal Users from Marketing Cloud. To do that, I'm creating an automation to populate/refresh a Data Extension with all the Active users in my org. However, I do not want the frozen users to receive these comms.

As far as I'm aware, the 'IsFrozen' field is part of the UserLogin object and I need the UserPermissions.ManageUsers permission to see that object in Salesforce. With that permission, the object will be available as an Entity in the Synchronized Data Extensions to activate? If not, how can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but I don't think you can include the that object and that field in a Synchronized Data Extension.

However, you can manually export it by this SOQL from Salesforce CRM

```
select 
  Id, 
  Name, 
  Email, 
  Profile.Name, 
  Profile.UserLicenseId, 
  IsActive 
from 
  User 
where 
  IsActive = true 
  and Id NOT IN (select UserId FROM userlogin WHERE IsFrozen = true)
```

Note: you may want to filter on the `Profile.UserLicenseId` also.

Then import the results to a DE in MC